# How to open a .sql like a .pks?

Tags: oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

Anyone knows how to open .sql files with the same editor of .pks files in Oracle Sql Developer tool?

Comment: Do you want to change the default editor for all .sql files, or do you want to open a single .sql file with the code editor?

Comment: I'm trying to open a single file. We are dealing with a project in which all db files are saved with .sql extension, even packages. So, when I open a package script I would want to switch the editor to .pks editor. Is that possible?